# .Net Core web app delploy to IIS with Server Error

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, .net-core

Guru, I have try to deploy my .net core web app to local IIS, 
with 500 error, it looks something wrong with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\LocalTest1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

, I have enabled the stdoutLogEnabled, it does not give me any valueable info, any advice?

Comment: furthermore, in debug mode in VS, it works fine, only after I successful deploy to inetpub folders, the error occur

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-story-of-publishing-net-core-web-apps-for-beginners-6121662dd8c4